# Run *.jar file on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I copied the program from this link: [Memo Game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85833/basic-memory-match-game-in-java) and turned it on on Eclipse. Everything worked properly. What if I want to try it on my Android device? I download BlueStacks and exported Eclipse project into *Runnable JAR file*. Then I tried to turn this file on using [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325619) but I couldn't do it. I found the whole process very difficult and I am sure there are easier methods to write Android applications.

**Main question:** What should I do in order to turn on a normal Eclipse application that I write and test on my computer on Android? **Is it at all possible?**

I know that there is a program called Android Studio, but there you use specific commands that I am not familiar with. That's why I am asking about turning on the same code I write on computer but on Android.

Comment: That application uses Swing for its UI. Android does not have Swing. That application will need to be rewritten to use Android APIs for its UI.

Comment: It explains everything. Thank you very much :)